# Ajax in Laravel 5.3 accessible by everyone

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I am new to Laravel, so sorry for my code..

I am trying to integrate a jquery library with my Laravel project.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    return view('products');

}

public function data()
{
    $products = Product::all();

    return $products->toJson();

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/products', ['as' => 'products', 'uses' => 'ProductController@index']);
Route::get('/products/data', ['as' => 'products.data', 'uses' => 'ProductController@data']);
```

**View**

```
<script>

    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/products/data/',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Everything works, but if I go to /products/data/ I can see the json on the browser. That should not happen!

Am I doing it right? It this the right way of getting json data from the database into the view?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long this information is not usefull for an attacker you've nothing to worry about. Product information is most likely not a thing you want if you want to do some harm to a website.

Make sure information about users doesn't transfer over a `GET Request`. Because this way someone who wants to do harm to your website has access to information they want to achieve. Make sure this data travels over a `POST Request` so they can't get access to the information very easy. Also make sure you hash information that should be only in the hands of the user him or herself or other trusted sources.

In this situation i don't really see anything wrong with your approach at first sight.

A little more information about this subject can be found here: [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. But isn't any way for me to block the access to that URL over the browser?

Comment: @devwebapp I don't think that is possible. You could for example only access the `GET` url by logged in users for showing products. But this is optional. You could also go for a `POST` request so data is not available on the url but you're not posting any data so i don't think it is required in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Request `wantsJson` or `ajax` method

**Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function data(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::all();

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return $products;
    }

    return abort(404);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. With this approach I get an error. "Trying to get property of non-object". Any idea why?